# Multiple installation of postgres in AWS instance, why or how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I was checking why some services were not working as expected in an AMI Linux instance in AWS and after some time I found there were **two** PostgreSQL installations, both version 9.6 located at:

```
/var/lib/pgsql96/
```

and

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/
```

I don't know how it ended up like this. But another issue I found is that the service script (postmaster) found in `init.d` tried to use the `data` folder of the first path (`/var/lib/pgsql96/data`) but for the applications to run successfully I needed to use the `data` folder of the second path (`/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data`)

How could the system end up with these two PostgreSQL folders? Is that something common, maybe after trying an upgrade, reinstall or some process?